# Equivalent formulas for electric current density

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

I am reading an article that states that the "ratio of current to the area for a given surface is known as current density" and is defined as

$J = \frac{I}{A}$ where $I$ is the current and $A$ is the area of the surface. Wikipedia provides this equation: $J = \sigma E$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity. How are the two the same?

Answer (score 3):

The definition of current density is $J = \frac{I}{A}$, or more precisely, $J = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 I}{\mathrm{d}^2 A}$. It is always true, by definition.

$J=\sigma E$ is a different equation: it's equivalent to Ohm's law, which you know better as $V = IR$. Ohm's law is not universal; it only works for certain materials, called ohmic materials.

For an ohmic material, you can show that the two formulas for $J$ are equivalent using the formula for resistivity, $R = \rho L/A$, and the fact that $\rho = 1/\sigma$, together with the relationship $\vec{E} = -\nabla V$.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it simple:

You can think $J = I/A$ as one definition of the $J$.

Since the current $I$ is related with the eletric field, then the $J$ must depend from the electric field as well. As a first approximation we guess a linear relationship between $J$ and $E$. Naturally it is not a linear relationship, but works well as approximation in some cases (solid and liquid isotropic materials for instance). Therefore, we say:
$$J = \sigma E$$

The proportionality constant $\sigma$ of the linear relation, is interpreted as a conductivity constant, because the greater the $\sigma$ the greater the current $I$ keeping constant the electric field $E$.